# my error in 12.04 update; won't boot now

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I ran the update and the prompt said it was complete and to restart.  I have a kvm switch and it was set to the other computer during the update.  The updated machine did not recognize the mouse or keyboard.  So, I "pulsed" the power switch to restart it.  Upon restart the system would not boot.  Is there a way to recover this system without a complete redo?

Comment: In what way does your computer "not boot"? I can think of lots of possible ways that could happen and I don't know which one might be happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Recovery Mode from the boot menu (the list of operating systems, looks like the screenshot below). Hope it'll do the trick.

[image: screenshot of GRUB v1.98 boot menu]